# BAT: Parse Output File For Error Handling

Tags: error-handling, batch-file, for-loop

I have a process that is kicked off by a scheduled batch file daily. I need to have error handling built in to restart the process if there is an error. All works great most days but I get a time out error once a month or so that is unavoidable. The process does not output an errorlevel to the bat file so I need to be able to parse the output file to determine if the process needs to restart.

I tried using the `FOR /F` function to pass the contents of line 12 as a variable to use in an `IF` statement but I have been unsuccessful. I can obviously skip to line 12 but then I am left dealing with the tokens of the remaining lines. Does anyone have any suggestions that I could try?

Output file when all is well:

(Line Numbers Added for Readability)

```
1  Pricing Script
2   
3  ________________________________________________________________________ 
4
5  Retrieve Prices
6
7  Date of price file: 070912
8  Regular only 
9  Connecting to server intdata.com
10 TCP/IP connection established
11  
12 TySymb          Interactive Data
+400 more lines
```

Output file when there is an error:

```
1  Pricing Script
2  
3  ________________________________________________________________________ 
4 
5  Retrieve Prices
6  
7  Date of price file: 071012
8  Regular only 
9  Connecting to server intdata.com
10 TCP/IP connection established
11 Time Out
12 General Time Out. The User ID and/or Password might be incorrect.
```

Comment: So you just want the 12th line in the output file?

Comment: That's one way to approach it, if I can get that I should be set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply look for the error message in the output using FIND or FINDSTR. I wouldn't worry about the line number.

```
find "General Time Out. The User ID and/or Password might be incorrect." "yourFile.log" && (
  echo Timeout occurred, you must put code here to restart
)
```

or

```
findstr /c:"General Time Out. The User ID and/or Password might be incorrect." "yourFile.log" && (
  echo Timeout occurred, you must put code here to restart
)
```

Comment: +1. Neat. But how do you know that that's the only possible error message?

Comment: @EitanT - I don't obviously :) But as long as all possible error messages are known (or at least a distinct fragment) then FINDSTR can be used with multiple /C arguments, one per message. Or FINDSTR could be used with regular expressions to match some distinct error message pattern.

Answer (score 0):

This will test only line 12 of your file for a given string:

```
@echo off
for /f "skip=11 tokens=*" %%i in (your_log_filename) do (
 echo %%i | find "General Time Out" >nul
 goto check
)

:check
if errorlevel 1 (echo No Timeout occured!) else (echo Timeout occured)
```